# remove specifying the full path in sudoers

Tags: linux, sudoers

I am trying to add a NOPASSWD entry for 'sudotest.sh' (or any script/binary that requires sudo) in my /etc/sudoers file (redhat) but in order to make it work, I must specify the full path. The following entry works just fine:

%jenkins ALL=(ALL)NOPASSWD:/home/vts_share/test/sudotest.sh The problem is that the script might move to a different directory. I tried as giving /home/*/sudotest.sh but didn't work for me when I tried to execute sudo ./sudotest.sh,it gave me you dont have root permission

Note:I can't have permission to /bin/sh directory too.

Comment: Are you sure you'd want something like this being possible? Just because a script has a specific name shouldn't allow me to execute it with superuser-rights, should it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea to do what you are trying to do. "The problem is that the script might move to a different directory." Ask you the question of who is going to move it. Suppose that a malicious user create a `sudotest.sh` somewhere in the path. Then it will be this malicious file which get executed with root access. So my answer is **Don't do it !**